# Forms showing up as plain text in Laravel 5

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, text

I'm pretty new to the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) universe.

So I was following a tutorial on OpenClassrooms and the tutorial is about Laravel 4 and I'm using Laravel 5, so I went through some trouble trying to adapt my controllers and getting them to work on my project, and after getting rid of many errors concerning the namespace dependencies, I'm getting a form which looks like text html that is not processed, here's what's showing up:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://gappsl/users" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input
    name="_token"
    type="hidden"
    value="HMfnLvctXZqOuCpSdeJXML76L2KoPsZtadpIqOnm">
  <label for="nom">Enter your name:</label>
  <input name="nom" type="text" id="nom">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here's my controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers; use \View; 
  class UsersController extends Controller {
    public function getInfos() {
      return View::make('infos');
    }

    public function postInfos() {
      echo 'The name is ' . Input::get('nom');
    }
  }
?>
```

Here's my views:

```
@extends('tempform')
@section('content') {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'users')) }} {{ Form::label('nom', 'Enter your name:') }} {{ Form::text('nom') }} {{ Form::submit('Submit') }} {{ Form::close() }}
@stop

<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <body>
    <p> @yield('content') </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: While improving the formatting I saw there is a missing `</head>` in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5, `{{ }}` (for example `{{ Form::open() }}` escapes the variables in blade templates.

In Laravel 5, use `{!! Form::open() !!}` instead. Also, double check that it actually is a blade template you're using (and not a straight up PHP one).

Answer (score 0):

for Laravel Framework version 5.2.34 this worked for me

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/admin/expertise')) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

with one `{` and two `!!` .